# Does converting DBF to xls affect macros?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that runs without problem if data is manually typed into the spreadsheet. Manually typing is obviously not the most efficient and the database system I'm receiving the data from outputs it into a dbf file.

When I convert the dbf to excel and paste the data into the sheet I need to run the macro I get a type mismatch error (in between the **)

```
Sub TimeDifference()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Avg Downtime").Select
Range("G3:H500").Select
   Selection.ClearContents
i = 3
j = i + 1
For i = 3 To 500 
If Cells(i, "A").Value = Cells(j, "A").Value Then 'checks if TagID are the same
    If Cells(i, "C").Value > 0 And Cells(j, "D").Value > 0 Then 'checks if there has been a complete alarm on/off process
    *Cells(j, "G").Value = Cells(j, "B").Value - Cells(i, "B").Value* 'calculates downtime
    End If
End If
j = j + 1
Next i
```

It's just a simple subtraction and when I manually do it there's no problem. I don't know what I can do to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely a null or non numeric value in B where you are trying to do math with it.

Try something like this.

```
Sub TimeDifference()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim iRow As Integer

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Avg Downtime")
ws.Activate

iRow = 3
ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate

Do While iRow <= 500
    If ws.Range("A" & iRow).Value = ws.Range("A" & iRow + 1).Value Then
        If ws.Range("C" & iRow).Value > 0 And ws.Range("D" & iRow + 1).Value > 0 Then
             if isnumeric(ws.Range("B" & iRow + 1).Value) = true and isnumeric(ws.Range("B" & iRow).Value) = true then
                ws.Range("G" & iRow + 1).Value = ws.Range("B" & iRow + 1).Value - ws.Range("B" & iRow).Value
             end if
        End If
    End If

iRow = iRow + 1
Loop

End sub
```

Comment: I had to fix this a little (floating End if) but  I still get the same type mismatch error at the same line.

Comment: It is most likely a null or non numeric value in B where you are trying to do math with it.

Comment: I made a change above based on you edit. see the three lines where the "Set ws =" and ws.Activate and new line "ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate"  Let's see if that is equal to selecting a cell.